# Coder for boolean values?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've scanned through the Java SDK docs but am either missing something obvious or don't see one. What would an appropriate coder be for Boolean values? This seems fundamental enough that I'm assuming the former is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Serializable` classes such as Booleans are by default encoded using a `SerializableCoder`. In most cases it should work, unless you need to group by the boolean value (then you'll get an error that it's not a deterministic coder and you'll have to implement one yourself).